# error when opening Word attachment to email from view activity

Tags: wordpress, email

I've sent an email with an MS Word document as an attachment. When I look at the email on the activity log and open the attachment with Word then I get a warning message saying there is unreadable content in the document. It allows me to open the document anyway and doing a comparison with the original it says its the same. If I open the document from the email that is sent then its fine.

Not a big deal for me, but could be worrying for another user. I'm using CiviCRM 5.15.1 (and WordPress, but doubt that is relevant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried again just now and all seems OK, so I think the answer is the same as [JPG files uploaded as notes can't be viewed](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/34053/jpg-files-uploaded-as-notes-cant-be-viewed) and that it was caused by a blank line in the functions.php in the theme